# Is there some standard Haskell library dealing with process communication?

Tags: haskell

Googled a little bit, but still not sure whether there is some standard library in Haskell dealing with inter-process communication stuff, since I am new to Haskell, I also hope that the library is well documented, better some small example (e.g. passing some data types and use them)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many commercial and open source IPCs have Haskell bindings:

[0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:haskell)

[Thirft](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Thrift-0.6.0)

[Messagepack](http://msgpack.org/)

I have made the best experiences with Messagepack because it is quite light weight.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple library to solve the most basic aspects of this problem: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ipcvar